# In R, why are the arguments for the bias() function from SimDesign input "actual_temp" followed by "predicted_temp", and not the other way around?

Tags: r

Hello everyone – I am new to programming in R and find the arguments needed for the bias() function from SimDesign a bit confusing.

Any explanation or clarification would be much appreciated.

The example that I am learning from is as follows:

```
install.packages("SimDesign")
library(SimDesign)

actual_temp <- c(68.3, 70, 72.4, 71, 67, 70)
predicted_temp <- c(67.9, 69, 71.5, 70, 67, 69)

bias(actual_temp, predicted_temp)

[1] 0.7166667
```

I am wondering why the **actual_temp** vector is input before the **predicted_temp** vector, when the bias() function usage text specifies that the *estimate* comes before the *parameter*?

Below is the text from the help document for this function:

```
bias(
  estimate,
  parameter = NULL,
  type = "bias",
  abs = FALSE,
  percent = FALSE,
  unname = FALSE
)
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is so?

My understanding is that the *estimate* argument would be the **predicted_temp** vector, and that the *parameter* argument would be the **actual_temp** vector. However, this is not what was shown to me.

I tried to reverse the two arguments to follow my understanding of the vectors and what they mean, and was given a negative value for bias instead:

```
> bias(predicted_temp, actual_temp)

[1] -0.7166667
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Shouldn't the **predicted_temp** come before the **actual_temp**?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of bias that is being used in that function with default arguments for the other parameters is the usual one, `mean(estimate - parameter)`.  So your understanding is correct,
and whatever source you used for the example is not.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I appreciate your knowledge! So for clarification, would the returned negative value "-0.7166667" be correct in this example?